# SideNavigation with Image | java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(111984000bytes) bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I have made a SideNavigationDrawer for the dashboard of my application.

I have used-

```java
navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view2);
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
```

in my java file.

The XML code for NavigationView is-

```xml
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view2"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
```

The header file contains the background image and an extra image, which I think are causing this error.
header file code-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_back_min"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/side_nav_min"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/belgrano"
        android:text="Gym"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/belgrano"
        android:text="www.alivez.com"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**On My Actual Samsumg device the SideNav works with a little bit of stutter and mid-lag while opening from the left side but on Xiaomi device the App Activity crashes and redirects to the previous Activity.**

I think the background image of the LinearLayout `android:background="@drawable/side_nav_back_min"` and the image in the ImageView `android:src="@drawable/side_nav_min"` are causing some error.

Logcat is shown below-

```
2020-10-18 16:02:25.158 28442-28442/com.example.bottomnav E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bottomnav, PID: 28442
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(111984000bytes) bitmap.
        at android.graphics.RecordingCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(RecordingCanvas.java:280)
        at android.graphics.BaseRecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseRecordingCanvas.java:88)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:548)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21551)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20420)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4417)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4177)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21554)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20420)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4417)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4177)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20411)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4417)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:5030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4177)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21554)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:4429)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20420)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4417)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4177)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21554)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.draw(ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java:109)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20420)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4417)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1478)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4177)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21554)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20420)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4401)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4374)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20380)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4401)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4374)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20380)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4401)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4374)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20380)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4401)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4374)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20380)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4401)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4374)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20380)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:575)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:581)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3734)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3529)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2866)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7781)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1031)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:854)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
2020-10-18 16:02:25.158 28442-28442/com.example.bottomnav E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1016)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I tried to compress the Image but the issue still persists. What is the max Bytes size for bitmap in the canvas for the android app?

Comment: Well use smaller images.

Comment: Already the sizes of the images are 40KB and 15KB

Comment: File size is not that important. Its the resolution that counts. Number of pixels in WxH.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap

this is the way you can control the quality of you're bitmap :

```
public boolean compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat format, 
                int quality, 
                OutputStream stream)
```

Write a compressed version of the bitmap to the specified outputstream. If this returns true, the bitmap can be reconstructed by passing a corresponding inputstream to BitmapFactory.decodeStream(). Note: not all Formats support all bitmap configs directly, so it is possible that the returned bitmap from BitmapFactory could be in a different bitdepth, and/or may have lost per-pixel alpha (e.g. JPEG only supports opaque pixels).
This method may take several seconds to complete, so it should only be called from a worker thread.
and you're last question about the size is:
Hint to the compressor, 0-100. The value is interpreted differently depending on the 0-100  `int quality` data for the value!

Comment: can you be more specific with reference to my code?

Comment: @SAHEELSAPOVADIA  As you can see i just send an function for you!
you should pass the image that you enter !
you can customize you're app by letting the user chanage the picture of that slider and also by this function reduce the quality and byte size of it so you dont need to worry about the size and quality anymore it always check the image with this function and optimize the picture with value that you want to..

Comment: I simply reduced the background Image Pixel Dimensions and it worked.